# is there a way to manage the duration of the remote notification to be displayed longer on the banner?

Tags: swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications, notificationcenter, nsusernotificationcenter

I am working on an App which I want the Playload notification to remain presented in the banner until the user clicks on it. 
I have two cases:

- App in background, after opening the app (not through the notification) the notification disappears.
- App in foreground, the notification will be presented on the banner (I used: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate for that) but after few seconds it disappears.

is there a way to manage the notification duration, I want it to be presented until the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as a Banner Style. It can be set to either Temporary or Persistent with persistent banners requiring user interaction to disappear. You can not manipulate the duration of your notifications being displayed on screen. The banner style for the application can only be changed by the user in the notification settings for your application:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick answer, so it can be managed only by the user.  There is no other alternative.

Comment: Yes, only the user can choose the banner style